# Replace particular images in a word file with Text

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am manually deleting a particular image present at the beginning of multiples paragraphs in my word file and replacing it with the text "Picture_replaced". Could somebody please help me with VBA script to perform the above activity automatically.

Note:
The image/picture is always present at the beginning of the paragraph.
There are multiple lines which contain the same image to be replaced. Not every line has this particular image.
There are other images/pictures that are present in the file, which should not be touched.

Answer (score 0):

The following macro replaces all instances of the penguins image.

```
Public Sub removePenguins()

    Dim objPic As InlineShape
    For Each objPic In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
        If objPic.AlternativeText = "Penguins.jpg" Then

            objPic.Select

            Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
            Selection.TypeText Text:="[Image replaced] "


        End If
    Next objPic
End Sub
```

Just replace the AlternativeText condition with the alternative text of your image.

Comment: Thanks for a fast reply. could you please explain how to find the AlternativeText associated with an image. Is it a characteristic of the image ? I find height =0.34' and Width =0.34' for the image I wish to replace.

Comment: Right click->Format Picture-> Alt Txt tab doesn't have any details.

Comment: I got the alternative text from debugging the macro and inspecting the objPic object. It seems to be the filename by default. If you put a breakpoint on the "if objPic..." and look at the value of objPic you should see what it is for you.